# WPF, WCF and Code First - Disconnected mode

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, ef-code-first

Some architecture dilemma:
I'm using WPF as my client-side, EF Code First as my Data Access Layer, and WCF to connect between those. My probelm is hou to reupdate the UI after I did some changes to the DB, for example:

1. User insert new "Person" on the UI (ID=0)
2. User save the "Person" to the DB (ID=10, for example)

When talking about one user it's very simple - I can return the ID and update my UI as well (so next change to this person will be considered as "Update"), but what about adding more than one user at once, or updating other properties that was calculated on the server? should I return the whole graph? not to mention is very hard to remap it on the client side.

Before CodeFirst we could use STE, but it has it's own problems. anyone knows about known CodeFirst approach?

Would be happy to hear your voice.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can send as the request to your wcf service the dateTime of your last update in client-side. But in the server-side you take all `Persons` which was updated/added after that dateTime and return it as the result. In this way you will get only modified/added `Person`s from your server-side.

So add lastUpdate collumn to your entity `Person`.

**EDIT 1**

If you want to server update the information in client but not client ask for news from server.

You can use the way like it works in `Web Programming`.

(1)The `client-side` asks `server-side` - "hey, my last update was at 20:00 10.02.2013", then server looks into DB - "is news after 20:00 10.02.2013?" if yes:

a) returns the news to the client

if no news in DB:

b) He dont returns null, but he does Thread.Sleep(somevalue). He sleeps then repeats the query to db and asks is "there news in db". So it's all repeats untill the news in DB will apear. After news in db appears he return the `List<data>` which is in updated after the dateTime. After that client gets the data he goes back to the point - (1).

So you dont make a lot of requests to the server but making only one request and wait for the news from the server.

Notice 2 things:

1) If the client waits too long the server side will throw the exception(dont remember actually the error code but it's not important now), so you have to catch this exception on `client-side` and make a new request to `server-side`. Also you have to configure on the `server-side` as long as you can wait time, to minimize the amount of requests from client.

2) You have to run this `data-updater` in the new thread not in the main, where the application runs.

How it will looks from the code(it may not work, i just want to show you the logic):

Server side:

```
public List<SomeData> Updater(DateTime clientSideLastUpdate)
{
     List<SomeData> news = new List<SomeData>();
     while(true)
     {
         List<SomeData> news = dbContext.SomeData.Where(e=>e.UpdateDateTime > clientSideLastUpdate).ToList();
         if(news.Count()>0)
         {
             return news;
         }
     }
}
```

Client-side:

```
public static void Updater()
{
    try
    {
        var news = someServiceReference.Updater(DateTime clientSideLastUpdate);
        RenewDataInForms(news);
        Updater();
    }
    catch(ServerDiesOrWhatElseExcepption)
    {
        Updater()
    }
}
```

And somewhere in the code you run this updater in the new thread

```
 Thread updaterThread = new Thread(Updater());
 updaterThread.Start();
```

**Edit 2**

if you want update by one request all entities but not only `SomeData` then you have to add Dto object which will contain the List of every entities you want to be updatable. The `server-side` will complete and return this Dto object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You right, it's an option in order to support updates for multi clients. but i'm looking for more general way to achive this goal even without getting all updates from other clients.

Comment: You want to connect 2 or more clients directly to each other not  through the Wcf-server?

Comment: Yes, but my question is more about one client - how should I update the client with details from the server (like STE does) after update?

Comment: Oh, you want that server send the information to the client but not client ask for new items and server answers?